# IMG tag's SRC updation causing memory leaks

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dom

I have the following code in my HTML page,

```
<img src="#"  height="50" width="20" id='LogoID'>

function OnUpdateWebCamIMage(src) {
        document.getElementById('LogoID').src = src;
      }
```

Now am calling the JavaScript function multiple times in a second to update the image in the browser. When this is running, i could see that the physical memory consumption is always increasing until it's closed.

Is there a way around to make this work without the memory leak issue?

I been testing this on IE 11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to delete the image element, and create a new one for every new image. Hopefully the garbage collector will kill it. Maybe another way to do this by adding a no-cache header to the images. I don't have better tips...

Comment: Did you try this with other browsers?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to use MJPEG or something.